# UISwitch to perform very simple operation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiswitch

This may seem very silly, maybe i am not understanding it correctly.

I have a UISwitch in my scene.

```
 when a login button is clicked

     if the switch is on - do some thing
     if the switch is off - do something else
```

when i first add the switch and run the app i can switch it on and off but if i then add an outlet to my viewcontroller.h the switch is then greyed out. (most likely because it wants me to write my own animation and action???)

From my understanding for this i shouldnt need to create an action for it i just want to simply no if the switch is on or off.

Is this possible or do i need an action for it?

Comment: you want switch to off by default ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not changing the `enabled` property of your switch instead of changing its `on` property?

Comment: by ON/OFF default is irrelivant, if i add the switch to the scene and make no refrences to anything so the switch does nothing it can be turned on and off, i then drag a refernecing object from the switch to the header file, so all i am doing is declaring it. if i then run the app the switch is grey out and cannot be turned on or off. I havent changed any of the settings for the switch at that point

Comment: @Rob85 Add an action for UIControlEventValueChanged event to UISwitch. For this you don't need to connect as IBOutlet. And check the UISwitch's isOn property in this method.

Comment: thanks guys, the below answer was what i needed, i was making a silly mistake when declaring the switch in the header file, see below comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write any animation related code just follow below step and you can achieve what you want.

1. create a IBOutlet in your .h file. Connect it to UISwitch in storyboard

```
@interface FirstTabViewController : UIViewController {

    __weak IBOutlet UISwitch *switchLogin;
}

-(IBAction)btnLoginClicked:(id)sender;
```

2. write below code in your .m file

```
   -(IBAction)btnLoginClicked:(id)sender {

      if (switchLogin.on) {
          //switch is on do whatever you want
          NSLog(@"switch is on do whatever you want");
      }
      else {
          //
          NSLog(@"switch is off do whatever you want");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, the reason it didnt work for me was because i had declared the UISwitch out side of the brackets in the.h file. Your code made me realise this :-)